# docker - composer install and permissons in docker volumes - mkdir fails

Tags: docker, jenkins, permissions, docker-compose

I have 3 docker containers Apache, php and a temp_php_build container.
The temp_php_build container is created by
`docker-compose build temp_php_build`.
  It executes the `composer install` and that should create a folder in a shared volume.
This shared volume should later be copied to Apache and the PHP container.
Everything runs on Jenkins and the mounted volume is owned by `jenkins:jenkins`.

[image]

When the temp_php_build container performs its composer installation, some directories in the mounted volume fail to be created because the parent folders are not writable by the group or world.

[image]

I tried to give uid:gid 1000:1000 to the shared folders, which works temporarily, but since the workspace is whiped out on every Jenkins build, the permissions are reassigned.

How can this problem with Docker permissions be fixed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed this with letting jenkins omit an chown and firing up the php-build container and running composer install from the running container.

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /srv/www/htdocs/webapp
sudo chmod -R 775 /srv/www/htdocs/webapp
cd /srv/www/htdocs/webapp
docker-compose up -d --build php-build-container
docker exec php-build-container composer install
```

Afterwards I make sure that the permissions are reseted so that docker save is working again and the workspace can be whiped out by the next jenkins build